# Is it ok to include an image in email signatures?

Tags: copywriting, email, marketing

Over the years my company has had anniversaries, won awards, and done various other noteworthy things. For each of these "major" events, someone in HR will ask everyone in the company to include some left floating image in their email signature.

I understand the (perceived) marketing value of including accomplishment-type images in a signature. The main reason I avoid this is I don't like how some email clients interpret images in signatures as attachments -- it is misleading. Also, my personal opinion is it adds too much visual clutter and distracts from my (hopefully) brief message.

Are there other pros and cons of including in images in an email signature?

[image: email with images in signature]

Comment: for your reference: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/02/04/the-art-and-science-of-the-email-signature/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your key question: yes, it is OK to include images in email signatures.

You accepted the value of this approach in your own response:

> I understand the (perceived) marketing value of including accomplishment-type images in a signature.

However, main pet peeves (yes, these are pet peeves because not everyone is equally bothered by embedded images showing up as attachments) come with the implementation approach, such as:

1. How are the images added? Are they hosted externally and loaded when message is opened causing security alerts in some email clients? Or are they embedded into messages? If so, will they be displayed as attachments in email clients?
2. How do the images fit visually in the signature? Do they respect the visual space of the signature? Or do they break it? Similar to the big square banner between name and contact details in the question example?
3. How do the images fit in the overall signature and the message? Are they thin and unobtrusive? Or are they huge and absorb the reader's focus?

To summarize, it is totally acceptable to embed images in signatures. For example, some companies include the company logo and social profile icons. Some add thin banners at the bottom for marketing announcements.

The other question is *how are they embedded*? And like any design work, one can do this thoughtfully by crafting neat banners which only add to the visual aesthetics of the message. Or they can completely ruin it.

Specifically, when it comes to

> some email clients interpret images in signatures as attachments

...in my tests, images embedded into messages in Outlook *in a specific way* are not displayed as attachments when viewed in Outlook and Gmail. However, there are many different email clients and, just like browsers, they treat the same code in different ways. After all, an email message is text, just like HTML, crafted according to specifications.

Mobile is a separate consideration - the same emails which showed up fine in Outlook and Gmail Web, didn't show images in a Gmail client on Android (nor did they show up as attachments).

**BONUS: Technical Details: How NOT to Display Images as Attachments**

When it comes to *how*, one way to embed images so that they don't show up as attachments is to use the proper `Content-Disposition` attribute on the embedded image. The default value for `Content-Disposition`  is `attachment`. For images not to be displayed as attachments, they should be set as `inline`. Example:

```
--_006_1A1C458379D9264CAC45FB3E9912C6690A2C6AE887CANESTMSXaltu_
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="company_logo.jpg"
Content-Description: company_logo.jpg
Content-ID: <company_logo.jpg@01CFBD86.6D1761F0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="company_logo.jpg"; size=4634;
```

*Note that this is the code generated by the email client when a message is composed.*

References:

1. http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt
2. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

Comment: Very thorough response! Props to you.

Answer (score 0):

> my company has had anniversaries

Hey, mine too!

But seriously, I don't recommend it. You hit the main points and they are very valid.

> someone in HR will ask everyone...

HR is not marketing. Adding these "awards" and anniversaries is utterly useless to me as a client/customer. The awards have their place on a corporate website, but not in an email signature.

Comment: "HR is not marketing" - HR may simply be a communication channel and the actual idea might have originated in Marketing. Regardless, how companies structure their departments is irrelevant in this context. Also, the way this response is phrased it sounds very subjective. There are no rules or regulations which limit placement of marketing announcements to corporate websites.

Comment: @ulmas - Yep, you're right. HR could have simply been relaying the info. The way it's worded, it sounds as if HR is playing marketing. My point is HR should not be making these decisions. Regarding, "There are no rules or regulations". I never implied there were rules. The OP asked "Are there other pros and cons of including in images in an email signature?" I gave my personal opinion.

Comment: In this particular case, HR and marketing are one in the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you planning on having all of the email signature details in the image? If so I would recommend against it. It's a terrible idea because it's not even functional. None of the "links" are interactive.

I wouldn't put much weight into have images in the signature.